# Grease Pencil Render Error

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

When I try to either switch a grease pencil's material's alpha from 0 to 100 (ending in black) or change the material's fill color from black to white, a small number of strokes in the grease pencil object disappear during the render and/or don't show on the gray scale during a render and/or don't match the rest of the strokes in the object. It seems to be happening between frames.

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are they in the same layer?

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same layer and all have the same material.

Comment: I found a very, very crude work around. It appears to be happening to the last number of strokes. If I add additional strokes into the object, it appears to cause issues with those, by moving those outside of the rendering, the actual strokes in question don't appear to have issue.

Comment: Interesting. I am also using 2.81. Would imply to me probably a hardware or driver issue? To be clear, you didn't change any of the render options? Thanks.