# Discrepancy between the viewport render and actual render from the render engine.(Grease Pencil)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, layers

There appears to be a discrepancy between what one sees in render viewport and the rendered image. This issue is not specific to me. A fellow blender artist [posted similar issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162919).

It seems that the strokes that are added "afterwards" like colouring to fill gaps left by previous work- are not rendered by the engine as image.

Below is the Screenshot of the viewport:

[image: Screenshot of the viewport]

Below is the image rendered by the engine:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question in case someone is facing a similar issue:
In my case, there was a plane behind that grease pencil object that was intersecting the drawing while being rendered. Since it was hidden in the viewport but it was being selected for the render.
To see what objects are being rendered:
Go to outliner->Select filter->click on the camera icon
Then you will be able to select the specific objects you want to render from the outliner.